# Excel does not increment cell numbers correctly in formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I try to extend my formula to more cells of a column, the indices in that formula are not incremented correctly.

I set two cells to the values e.g. =D1 and =D3 and want to extend this to more cells of the column by selecting the two cells and dragging the fill handle horizontally.
What I would expect is that the subsequent cells are filled with =D5, =D7, =D9, ... and so forth. Instead what I end up with is =D1, =D3, =D3, =D5, =D5, =D7, =D7, ...

Excel even notes that this is nonsense ... well thanks Excel!

The cells in the left column are supposed to refer to every second cell in the right column:

[image]

What's the problem here?

It works if I just enter simple numbers 1, 2, 3, etc. But whenever I use cell numbers, I end up with crap whenever the offset greater than 1.

Comment: When dragging formulas and using relative references, this is the default behaviour of Excel. Each row/column reference is increased (or decreased) just 1 unit. It does not really look at your formula, it just updates the references based on current position by 1 unit. And this behaviour **cannot** be altered at all. You'll need to formulate something to get your desired output.

Comment: what formula you are applying and what result you want? can you please update here

Comment: For a regular step like that, I'd enter `zzD1` and `zzD3` in the first two cells, fill down, then replace `zz` with `=` using the Find/Replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
=TAKE(WRAPROWS(A1:A10,2),,1)
```

or

```
=INDEX(WRAPROWS(A1:A10,2),,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,(ROW(B1)-1)*2+1)
```

[image]